# How to make a resizeble window in pygame with Opengl

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, viewport, pyopengl

I want to make resizeble window in pygame using Pyopengl, and trying to use this code

```
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL, RESIZABLE)
```

or this

```
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL, pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Resizable does not appear. This code is working now:

```
def main():
pygame.init()
display = (800,600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL, RESIZABLE)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 500.0) # настройка камеры угол обзора дальняя и ближняя дистанция рендера
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
angle=0
distance=20
while True:
     ...
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must adjust the size of the viewport to the size of the window and the current framebuffer, by [`glViewport`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glViewport.html):

```py
glViewport(0, 0, display[0], display[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are importing [pygame.locals](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html) it should be like this:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL | RESIZABLE)
```

Basically all your [display flags](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) should be joined with a "|" (pipe) character.